Understanding time reversal symmetry in Classical Physics
By looking at Newton's second law, we can immediately infer said equation is symmetric in time:
$$m\frac{d^2\vec{r}}{dt^2}=\vec{F}(\vec{r},t)$$
since we can change $t\to -t$ and everything remains unchanged. Nonetheless, wouldn't this be the case if and only if $F$ had an even symmetry with respect to time? (i.e: $\vec{F}(\vec{r},-t)=\vec{F}(\vec{r},t)$). Naturally, a free particle ($F=0$) would present this symmetry, but this gives rise to 2 questions:

Although mathematically this time symmetry is a rather straightforward concept, what does it imply physically?
Why is this time symmetry not inherent to Newton's second law but instead dependent on the force we apply to our particle? I'm quite positive this does not imply different physics apply on different situations, but it does seem like it. Please tell me why this is wrong.

Having a look at Maxwell's equations now, we can see we are in the same situation: in the general case where the electric and magnetic fields vary with time:
$$\begin{cases}\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{E}=\frac{\rho(\vec{r},t)}{\varepsilon_0}\newline
\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{B}=0\newline
\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{E}=-\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}\newline
\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{H}=\frac{\partial \vec{D}}{\partial t}+\vec{J}\end{cases}$$
This system of equations is not symmetric under the transformation $t\to -t$. Nonetheless, if we were in the more simple case were the currents and charge densities do not depend on time (and therefore the fields are static), then we would have:
$$\begin{cases}\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{E}=\frac{\rho(\vec{r})}{\varepsilon_0}\newline
\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{B}=0\newline
\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{E}=0\newline
\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{H}=\vec{J}\end{cases}$$
And now the system is symmetric under said transformation. Again, this suggests there is different Physics acting on different situations. I know this can't be true, but I'm struggling to understand why.

You are blurring together two very different questions:  (1) Are the equations time-symmetric? and (2) Is some particular solution to those equation time-reversible?  (1) is what is normally meant by T-symmetry in physics; that you can change the sign of all the time-odd quantities like t and v and J and B and end up with the same equations.  Maxwell's equations are therefore time-symmetric.  No one expects (2) to be true in any given case, but that's not what is meant by "time symmetry".

To clarify, the left-hand side is always invariant under time reversal; the right-hand side is invariant if and only if $\mathbf F(\mathbf r,-t) = \mathbf F(\mathbf r,t)$.
If Newton's second law is symmetric under time reversal, then both $\mathbf r_1(t)$ and $\mathbf r_2(t) := \mathbf r_1(-t)$ are solutions to the general equation of motion, with initial conditions which are related by $\mathbf r_1(0) = \mathbf r_2(0)$ and $\mathbf r_1'(0) = - \mathbf r_2'(0)$ (as is probably not  surprising).
It's perfectly reasonable to have a force $\mathbf F(\mathbf r,t)$ which does not obey this constraint. Imagine a pendulum under the influence of a gravitational force which is changing with time, or a box sliding across the floor subject to a changing coefficient of friction.  In such cases, the fact that $\mathbf r_1(t)$ is a solution to the equation of motion does not imply that $\mathbf r_2(t) := \mathbf r_1(-t)$ is also a valid solution.
For instance, imagine a pendulum under the influence of a force $\mathbf F(t) = -mg e^{-t/T} \hat y$, where $T$ is some characteristic time. A solution to this equation would start off oscillating like a pendulum but gradually become a free particle; a solution to the time-reversed equation would oscillate at an exponentially increasing frequency. The solution sets of the equation and its time-reversed counterpart are very different.
As far as the Maxwell equations go, I am free to impose whatever current density $\mathbf J$ and charge density $\rho$ I like. Why should this be time-reversal symmetric, in general? Why should the current I applied yesterday have anything to do with the current I'm applying tomorrow?

The concept of “Time Symmetry” or “Time-Reversal Symmetry” in physics is NOT a statement that if you take a set of actual events, and re-parameterize those events with $t \to -t$, that nothing changes.  Obviously, a falling object would turn into a rising object under such a transformation.
Instead, the question is: Does this transformed set of events always look like a valid solution to the original (untransformed) equations?  If so, then the physics in question is time-symmetric.  On this account, F=ma is time-symmetric for any fundamental force; in any time-reversed solution one would compute the same gravitational or electromagnetic force.  Such forces are “time-even” (they don’t change sign upon time-reversal), and so is acceleration.  Both the falling object and the rising object obey the same equations, as they are both accelerating in the same direction.
You could also consider $F=ma$ for a non-fundamental force like friction, which would not be a time-symmetric equation.  Frictional forces appear to be time-odd (as they point opposite the time-odd velocity, and they will both change sign with time-reversal).  But if you recognize that this “force” is just an effective abstraction, and zoom down to a fundamental level, then modeling all the individual interactions makes all the forces again look time-even.  For this reason we say that fundamental physics equations are time-symmetric.
The same goes for Maxwell’s equations.  If you take any solution to those equations and time-reverse the solution, it will still obey the same equations.  (That’s because J and B and H are also time-odd quantities, and those will have opposite signs if you time-reverse everything.)
There’s a bit of a subtlety if you apply this logic to the Schrodinger equation.  This equation looks to be time-symmetric (if you treat the imaginary part of the wavefunction as time-odd).  But upon measurement one doesn’t use this equation, and instead uses the Born Rule to extract probabilities and collapse the wavefunction.  The collapse process is not time-symmetric (there’s no procedure where you “uncollapse” a wavefunction).  And yet most physicists still think of quantum theory as a time-symmetric theory, presumably ignoring the collapse, and also setting aside the tricky issue of how to think about probabilities in a time-neutral manner.
Finally, getting back a bit to your original question, I’ll note that the quickest way to confuse oneself on this topic is to sneak in causal reasoning without realizing it.  (Causation is not mere correlation, as everyone knows by rote.)  When one is imagining “inputting” a Force $F(t)$ or a current $J(t)$ into a problem, you’re inevitably thinking of that input as the cause, and the other correlated quantities as an effect.  Time-reversing such a situation raises tricky questions, because one has to decide whether to keep the same causes (even if they flip from the beginning to the end) or instead swap them out for other different causes (changing the entire causal analysis).  These complications don’t come into play if you just think of solutions as a set of correlated facts, rather than as collections of causes and effects.
